# Defining routes in a separate file and using them inside index.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ionic-framework

I have this routes inside my `index.js`

```
import {
    createRouter,
    createWebHistory
}
from '@ionic/vue-router';
import {
    RouteRecordRaw
}
from 'vue-router';

const routes = [{
        path: '',
        redirect: '/tabs'
    }, {
        path: '/tabs',
        component: () => import('../views/tabs/TabRoot.vue'),
        children: [{
                path: '',
                redirect: '/tabs/home'
            }, {
                path: '/tabs/home',
                component: () => import('../views/tabs/Home.vue')
            }, 
        ]
    },


   //Sell
   
    {
        path: '/sell',
        component: () => import('../views/pages/sell/Sell.vue')
    },


    //Categories
    
    {
        path: '/trending',
        component: () => import('../views/pages/Trending.vue')
    }
]

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes
})

export default router
```

and i would like to define the follwoing routes isnide `others.js` file and have this inside

```
{
    path: '/crud_ui_landing_vehicles',
    component: () => import('../views/pages/sell/categories/Vehicles.vue')
},

{
    path: '/crud_ui_landing_properties',
    component: () => import('../views/pages/sell/categories/Properties.vue')
},
```

The imported routes should be used inside `const routes` array object.
How can i define and import the routes file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue js separate routes in different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370112/vue-js-separate-routes-in-different-files)

Comment: Nope it doesn't. I guess its something particular with ionic vue routing but the concept is helpful. Thanks

Comment: I suggest you tag this with something regarding ionic

Answer (score -1):

Using the spread operator

```js
// others.js
export const others = [...]
```

```js
import { others } from './others.js'
const routes = [
  ...others,
  
  {
    path: ...,
    component: ...
  },
  ...
]
```

Comment: I have done that and tried to concat routes that were existing and the imported routes `landing_ui_routes.concat(routes);` and nothing works.

Comment: Your question does not reflect that.